# Kafka commitAsync Retries with Commit Order

Tags: apache-kafka, commit, offset, kafka-consumer-api

I'm reading through *Kafka the Definitive Guide* and in the chapter on Consumers there is a blurb on "Retrying Async Commits":

> A simple pattern to get commit order right for asynchronous retries is to use a monotonically increasing sequence number. Increase the sequence number every time you commit and add the sequence number at the time of the commit to the *commitAsync* callback. When you're getting ready to send a retry, **check if the commit sequence number the callback got is equal to the instance variable**; if it is, there was no newer commit and it is safe to retry. If the instance sequence number is higher, don't retry because a newer commit was already sent.

A quick example by the author would have been **great** here for dense folks like me. I am particularly unclear about the portion I bolded above.

Can anyone shed light on what this means or even better provide a toy example demonstrating this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I think it is, but got to humble I could be wrong

```
      try {
        AtomicInteger atomicInteger = new AtomicInteger(0);
        while (true) {
            ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(5);
            for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
                System.out.format("offset: %d\n", record.offset());
                System.out.format("partition: %d\n", record.partition());
                System.out.format("timestamp: %d\n", record.timestamp());
                System.out.format("timeStampType: %s\n", record.timestampType());
                System.out.format("topic: %s\n", record.topic());
                System.out.format("key: %s\n", record.key());
                System.out.format("value: %s\n", record.value());
            }

            consumer.commitAsync(new OffsetCommitCallback() {
                private int marker = atomicInteger.incrementAndGet();
                @Override
                public void onComplete(Map<TopicPartition, OffsetAndMetadata> offsets,
                                       Exception exception) {
                    if (exception != null) {
                        if (marker == atomicInteger.get()) consumer.commitAsync(this);
                    } else {
                        //Cant' try anymore
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    } catch (WakeupException e) {
        // ignore for shutdown
    } finally {
        consumer.commitSync(); //Block
        consumer.close();
        System.out.println("Closed consumer and we are done");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the example! Makes sense but should the instantiation of the AtomicInteger happen before the loop to process the records, then increment this value in the loop, and finally set this value to the marker in the callback? I think without that you wouldn't be able to check if a later offset was committed since each offset would start with a value of 0 in this example. That seem correct?

Comment: consumer.poll is deprecated, how r u handling evetually the consumer_records ?

Comment: @TiagoMedici `consumer.poll(5)` is deprecated, change to `consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(5));` or whatever time you would like.  Per second question, the `ConsumerRecords<K,V>` are the records that you iterate.

Comment: i do prefer this way : public void receive(ConsumerRecord<?, ?> record, Consumer consumer) , once you don't define the poll, all messages arrive, in case you define a poll like : consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(5)), only 70% of messages arrived, anyway  i can retrieve the consumerRecord from scratch, my issue is to commit a single message and my consumer is commiting the entire partition, even if i indicate the offset, i was wondering the poll size could help !!!!